# How do I position a div at the bottom center of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have this css:

```
#manipulate
{
  position:absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#063;
  bottom:0px;
  right:25%;
}
```

I have this html:

```
<div id="manipulate" align="center">

</div>
```

How do we position that div at the bottom center of the screen?!?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`align="center"` has no effect.

Since you have `position:absolute`, I would recommend positioning it 50% from the left and then subtracting half of its width from its left margin.

```
#manipulate {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:#063;
    bottom:0px;
    right:25%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Comment: hmm..what the solution..anyway I can set it to the center?

Comment: You can dynamically set ```margin-left``` to ```-50%``` instead of giving a static value.

Comment: I devote because this css remove my text and put the div at the end of screen

Comment: I can't understand. Why to subtract half of width from left margin?

Comment: @MayankKataria I assume because `left: 50%` puts the left side in the center, and no the middle in the center.

Answer (score 93):

If you aren't comfortable with using negative margins, check this out.

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Your Text
</div>
```

Especially useful when you don't know the width of the div.

Answer (score 22):

Use negative margins:

```
#manipulate
{
  position:absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  margin-left:-150px;
  background:#063;
  bottom:0px;
  left:50%;
}
```

The key here is the `width`, `left` and `margin-left` properties.

Comment: Google - "position absolute center" you'll find articles on the topic

Comment: 4 seconds...that's enough to make a difference. :P

Comment: very true..I was asked to do it in the interview I had today..and I couldnt do it :(.... I wish I had google access :(

Comment: Don't worry too much, now you know :) They were obviously probing how much you know, which you'd only know this little trick by having had the need to use it...

Comment: Would this work as a style reference directly in html ? ... No css... `style="position:absolute;width:300px;height:300px;margin-left:-150px;background:#063;bottom:0px;left:50%;"`

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution with two divs:

HTML:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="center">
            Text here
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#center {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using a Flexbox worked for me:

```
#manipulate {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; // Centers the item
  bottom: 10px; // Moves it up a little from the bottom
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can center it using negative margins BUT please note that it'll center exactly on the center of the screen IF any containing div is NOT SET to position:relative;

For example. http://jsfiddle.net/aWNCm/

So, best way to exactly center this div is to set correct properties position properties for its containing divs too otherwise it will be lost in some random ways.

Answer (score 1):

First make a container so you can move it with more freedom:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="manipulate"></div>
</div>
```

then:

```
.container{
  height: 100vh; ------>adjust it. Should fit wherever you need to put it
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
}

#manipulate{
  width: min(70vw - 5px, 750px); ------>responsive stuff
  height: 90vh;
  margin-inline: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% working single line (Inline CSS Solve)

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Your Content Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

100% working single line (Inline CSS Solve)

```
<div style="padding: 20px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Your Content Here</div>
```