# Align button to the bottom of the page using MUI v5 in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to position the button exactly at the center bottom of the page irrespective of the content height in that page.

Excerpt from my code

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button: {
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    position: "absolute"
  }
});

export default function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Box>
        <Box>
          <Paper elevation={2} sx={{ width: "100%", height: "50vh" }}>
            Some data
          </Paper>
        </Box>
        <Box textAlign="center">
          <Button
            className={classes.button}
            variant="contained"
            sx={{ width: "200px" }}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-pagebutton-thrzy?file=/demo.js). Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This is more css related ([see other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383194/9236122)) but you as you manually set the width of the `Button` you can position it 50% from the left and then subtracting half of its width from its left margin:

```
bottom: 0,
left: "50%",
marginLeft: -100,
position: "absolute"
```

[see exemple](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-pagebutton-forked-c613w?file=/demo.js)